# Когда admob выплачивает денежные средства?

Tags: google-play, admob

2 мая в admob преодолел планку в 100$, хотелось бы узнать, в течении какого времени будет произведена выплата и какую сумму выплатят?

Comment: Имхо, вопрос никак не связан с тематикой stackoverflow. Данный вопрос уместнее направить в службу поддержки AdMob.

Comment: Возможно как и Adsense - после 15 числа каждого месяца

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[График платежей](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2772140?hl=ru):

> Выплаты AdMob производятся ежемесячно. В течение месяца ваши доходы
>   суммируются. В начале следующего месяца их итоговое значение
>   отображается на балансе вашего аккаунта в разделе Транзакции на
>   странице "Платежи". Если баланс превышает порог оплаты и в вашем
>   аккаунте не приостановлено получение выплат, деньги будут перечислены
>   около 21 числа месяца, следующего за расчетным.

Comment: Большое спасибо!